# New Visual Studio installation, tests not running in Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests

This question is very similar to other questions that also in some cases literally have the text "tests not running in Test Explorer" in the title. But, my context is a bit different. In those questions, there was a fair bit of investigation into what might be wrong with the *tests*. I am fairly confident nothing is wrong with the tests in this case.

I am one of hundreds of developers working on a project, and this project has a large bank of automated tests (though perhaps not as large as it ought to be :-P). Everybody is frequently running tests, and triggers fire when pull requests are made and merged to automatically run them then too. Tests were working fine for me as well. But, I have just been given a new laptop with better hardware specs, and I am trying to get it set up. On the new laptop, the project builds just fine (and noticeably faster :-) ), but the automated tests just *don't run*. I can't figure out why, and I'm looking for suggestions about what to check *in this context* -- given that there are hundreds of places where the exact same code is working perfectly, I really don't think the tests or test projects themselves are at fault here.

I have observed that the build output, apparently randomly, sometimes does not contain the test adapter files:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll
- xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll

If these files are missing, then `VSTest.Console.exe` also cannot run the test. But, usually rebuilding the project results in the files magically appearing, and then `VSTest.Console.exe` works just fine.

I haven't been able to ascertain a reason why the adapter files are sometimes put into the build output and sometimes not, and in either case, the Test Explorer within Visual Studio *always* fails to run the tests -- it discovers the tests just fine, puts several thousand items into the forest of trees, but when told to run tests, it just sits there for a minute or two and then returns to idle state with no output at all in the "Tests" output window.

This is a brand new installation of Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview, the exact same version that is on my old laptop, but on my old laptop the tests run fine. What do?? I don't know what to check next. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am thoroughly confused. I tried installing new features, I tried checking for system updates, I rebooted multiple times, and tests did not work. So, finally, I decided to make a cut-down minimal test project and see if I could observe any differences in Process Monitor between the two computers. I made a project with two tiny tests, one with NUnit and one with xUnit, and ... they worked. So, I opened up the big project again and hit Run Tests, and ... they worked. I am completely stumped, and the only advice I can offer to anyone finding this question with a similar problem is, just keep trying.